# Super conductors

Tags: electrical-resistance, superconductivity

We get a super conductor by cooling down a metal to a certain temperature, and this has 0 resistance but in the quantum model as the temperature of the metal is reduced, there are no electrons above the fermi level or more specifically no conduction electrons and hence no current, so how does this justify super conduction ?

Comment: Electrons form Cooper pairs, as far as I know you cannot use the Fermi sphere picture anymore (it is unstable or so).
But your question has nothing to do with superconductivity. You're essentially asking, for a regular material (non superconducting), why do they still conduct electricity at absolute zero temperature, because they shouldn't if there is no conduction electron.

Comment: And a guide to get the answer... is... when you integrate a Dirac delta times a function, you can get a result that's different from zero.

Comment: So, physically, there are still electrons that conduct electricity, right on the Fermi surface. (for non superconducting metals I'm talking).